# Select rows before multiple ids

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, union

I want to get 2 row IDs before rows with specified value.

So I have IDs and values in a table

```
ID   value
1,   x
3,   x 
7,   x
8,   error
9,   x
10.  x
11,  x
12   error
```

I want the two rows before the errors.

I can do this with hardcoded error row IDs

```
SELECT id FROM thetable WHERE id < 8 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2  
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM thetable WHERE id < 12 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2
```

Howewer I cannot hardcode the error id's, how can I do this for example with combine this with `SELECT id FROM thetable WHERE value = 'error'` or any other way?

I use sqlite 3, but I am interested in everything.

Comment: Were none of the answers to your previous seven questions acceptable?

Comment: I have wrote: this is sqlite3

Comment: Sorry, I forget to accept the answers (or didnt know, that I have to do this). I do it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new to SQLite so I have no idea about its syntax and all. But try below code if it works for you or not

```
select id,value
from (select *,rowid rid from tbl
order by id)
where rid in
(
  select rowid-1 from tbl
  where value = 'error'
  order by id
)or rid in
(
  select rowid-2 from tbl
  where value = 'error'
  order by id
)
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/37435/1)**

Comment: @aldmike what is the issue with that?? I have handled that scenario have check my demo??

Comment: Your demo was OK, I have deleted my Comment. I need now a little time to integrate and check the soultions :)
Thanks

Comment: @aldmike if you find this solution ok than mark it as an answer so others can refer to it.

Comment: +1 I didn't now about the rowid function in SQLLite but this *(as I mentioned in my answer)* makes the solution far more readable. Do note that you didn't select the **actual** error rows themselve but that's easy enough to add.

Comment: Oh no, it's not good, because my ID is the rowid too.

because: "If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID using any of four different names, the original three names described above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any context."
If an ID is skipped before the error, then I cant get the two row

Comment: @Lieven Maybe I need your previous solution, what you have deleted, because rowid is the same of the ID in sqlite, so I cannot use that when I skip id-s.

Comment: @aldmike - I have undeleted *(and fixed)* my statement.

Comment: @aldmike I didn't get you. What you are saying about ids. Please explain.

Comment: Ok. Your solution was not good for me, because sometimes there are skipped id's (like in my example and in your demo: after ID 1, comes the ID 3) and if I have an id what is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (like in my db the ID), then ROWID is only a alias of the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ID, and then the "rowid - 1" and "rowid - 2" isn't a good solution. 
I hope now you can catch it, my english is really bad, I know.

Comment: @jaychapani: here you can see what I tried to tell: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e04f7/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8836b/5)

---

I don't know if sqllite has ranking functions wich would make the solution a lot easier but following statement should work on any ANSI-92 compliant DBMS.

The gist of the solution is to

- Step1: Get all `error` ID's
- Step2: Get all ID's < the root ID's by using a GROUP BY clause and joining with the same query to retrieve the original error ID's
- Step3: Similar to step two but descend another level.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    (
              -- Select the ROOT value
              SELECT  ID, 0 AS GroupID
              FROM    thetable
              WHERE   value = 'error'
              UNION ALL

              -- Selects the ROOT value - 1 
              SELECT  MAX(t.ID) AS ID, te.ID AS GroupID
              FROM    thetable AS t
                      INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT  ID
                        FROM    thetable
                        WHERE   value = 'error'
                      ) AS te ON te.ID > t.ID 
              GROUP BY
                      te.ID

              UNION ALL        

              -- Selects the ROOT value - 1 - 1 
              SELECT  MAX(t.ID), te.ID
              FROM    thetable AS t
                      INNER JOIN (        
                        SELECT  MAX(t.ID) AS ID, te.ID AS GroupID
                        FROM    thetable AS t
                                INNER JOIN (
                                  SELECT  ID
                                  FROM    thetable
                                  WHERE   value = 'error'
                                ) AS te ON te.ID > t.ID 
                        GROUP BY
                                te.ID
                      ) AS te ON te.ID > t.ID
              GROUP BY
                      te.ID
            ) AS t                  

ORDER BY
        ID
```

**Edit**

FWIW: Should SQLite allow ranking functions and cte's, following statement returns the same result but is much more condensed.

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rn
          , ID
          , value
  FROM    thetable 
)
SELECT  q2.ID
FROM    q q1
        INNER JOIN q q2 ON q2.rn BETWEEN q1.rn - 2 AND q1.rn
WHERE   q1.value = 'error'
```

Comment: I need a little time :) Thanks

Comment: I cannot use the second one, becose no ROW_NUMBER() or equalent exists in sqlite. (If I well read), I try first one

Comment: Ok, the first way is good on sqlite after integration too. Only a little bit too huge and I have to understand.
Thanks, I will use it!

Comment: Here the first statement was allright, but when I wan't for example the 5 rows before and 2 rows after the error, then it is really huge. Can it smaller be on sqlite?

Comment: @ald mike - I don't have any experience with sqlite but if ranking functions are available (like rowid mentioned in jaycahpani's answer), it should be possible to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, value 
from test where id in (select id-1 from test where value = 'error')
```

This will work if you always look for the first id behind your error. If it can happen that you skip an id you can use MIN function to get the closest existing id.

Comment: It can happen, unfortunatly I don't know how can I then with MIN function solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM thetable 
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN value = 'error' THEN value ELSE ID END
 DESC
```